# How to call a phtml file in cms page to set page title

Tags: php, magento

In Magento how to call a phtml file in cms page to set page title which title I set in my phtml file? I am using

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('your title');
```

to set page title.

Answer (score 9):

To call a phtml file in a cms page or cms static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="templateFolder/your_template.phtml"}}
```

If you know, where the block file(php file) for your phtml file resides, then you can use it as type.

**Example:** Suppose you want to call new.phtml file that resides in catalog/product folder, and you know that its corresponding Block file(php file) resides in Catalog/Product folder, then you can use:

```
{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

More reading: [here](http://importantmagento.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-call-phtml-file-in-cms-page-in.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the title of the page from a template file when using it in a cms block or cms page because the `head` block is already rendered when the page (or block) content is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change page title from phtml file of cms pages as already told by @Marius

you need to add to it's design in cms page as given below :

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="setCustomTitle" translate="title"> <title> Custom Title </title> </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below XML piece under CMS > Pages > Manage Content > Select a specific CMS Page

Navigate to "Design" tab > Layout Update XML >

```
 <reference name="head">
     <action method="setCustomTitle" translate="title"> <title> Custom Title  </title> </action>
 </reference>
```

Make sure the CACHE folders are DELETED under below:
{Root Magento Folder}/var/cache
{Root Magento Folder}/var/full_page_cache

Hope this helps!

Happy Coding...